# Why isnt this definition working?

Tags: arrays, search, binary, function

```
def BinarySearch(searchItem,searchList):
    lower=0
    upper=len(searchList)-1
    while True:
        if lower== upper:
            return False,-1
        middle=(lower+upper)//2
        middleItem=searchList[middle]
        if searchItem==middleItem:
            return True,middle
        elif searchItem<middleItem:
            upper=middle
        else:
            lower=middle+1

BinarySearch(4,[0,1,4,7,8,9])
```

when I run the program there isnt an output how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is becuase you are not recieving the return of the function and printing it

```
des, val = BinarySearch(4,[0,1,4,7,8,9])

if(des == True):
    print "item present at", val
else:
    print "item not present"
```